# Scopes in Javascript AMD pattern

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps-api-3, requirejs, amd

I'm totally new to Javascript from Java, and I have had to start directly for the most difficult thing for me... developing an app using the Asynchronous Module Definition pattern...

I'm using the platform [**Weejot**](http://www.weejot.com/), which provides a [**framework**](http://docs.weejot.com/developer/api/index.html) to develop javascript web apps that uses [**AMD pattern**](http://docs.weejot.com/developer/reference/amd.html). All documentation [**here**](http://docs.weejot.com/developer/). You probably don't know it, but maybe you can help anyway if you know the AMD pattern...

Basically I have a module `MyController.js` that looks like this (note that most of the code is automatically generated, I only wrote the commented lines):

```
define([
    "js/util",
    "framework/Controller"
], function (
  util,
  Controller
){      
  function MyController(environment, connector) {
    Controller.call(this, environment);
    this.settings = environment.siteApplication.getSettings();
    this.connector = connector;        
    //Variable where I have some value stored
    this.myVariable = "hello";
  }    

  MyController.prototype = Object.create(Controller.prototype);

  util.extend(MyController.prototype, {
    //Function to show a map
    showMap: function (request, render) {
      //Get google maps script
      $.getScript("http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=KEY&sensor=false");          
      //Render is a framework object that basically shows the view "map.html" in full page mode
      render({name: "map", mode: "fullPage"});
    }    
  });

  return MyController;
});
```

This doesn't work fine, because after the line of `$.getScript(...)`, the script doesn't seem to be loaded, since I can't access the object `google.maps`, which should have been created...

I made it working by adding a callback function to the script url, like this:

```
$.getScript("http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=KEY&sensor=false&callback=drawMap");
```

The problem is that this callback function must be a *global* function, so I added the following function to the previous module (just before the `return` statement above):

```
window.drawMap = function () {
  var mapOptions = {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644);,
    zoom: 8,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  };
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), mapOptions);
}
```

And somehow, I get the map rendered perfectly... BUT, my problem is that I need to access the variable `myVariable` from the function `window.drawMap`, and I can't... is there any way to do it? or I just doing everything wrong from the beginning?

As I said I'm new to all this, and I'm getting crazy and in my try to make it working I've been adding and changing things to the point that I don't know what I'm actually doing... Any suggestion will be appreciated...

---

EDIT: if it's useful, this is the response when getting the Google Maps script (copied from Chrome's console):

```
window.google = window.google || {};
google.maps = google.maps || {};
(function() {

  function getScript(src) {
    var s = document.createElement('script');

    s.src = src;
    document.body.appendChild(s);
  }

  var modules = google.maps.modules = {};
  google.maps.__gjsload__ = function(name, text) {
    modules[name] = text;
  };

  google.maps.Load = function(apiLoad) {
    delete google.maps.Load;
    apiLoad([0.009999999776482582,[[["http://mt0.googleapis.com/vt?lyrs=m@216000000\u0026src=api\u0026hl=es-ES\u0026","http://mt1.googleapis.com/vt?lyrs=m@216000000\u0026src=api\u0026hl=es-ES\u0026"],null,null,null,null,"m@216000000"],[["http://khm0.googleapis.com/kh?v=128\u0026hl=es-ES\u0026","http://khm1.googleapis.com/kh?v=128\u0026hl=es-ES\u0026"],null,null,null,1,"128"],[["http://mt0.googleapis.com/vt?lyrs=h@216000000\u0026src=api\u0026hl=es-ES\u0026","http://mt1.googleapis.com/vt?lyrs=h@216000000\u0026src=api\u0026hl=es-ES\u0026"],null,null,"imgtp=png32\u0026",null,"h@216000000"],[["http://mt0.googleapis.com/vt?lyrs=t@131,r@216000000\u0026src=api\u0026hl=es-ES\u0026","http://mt1.googleapis.com/vt?lyrs=t@131,r@216000000\u0026src=api\u0026hl=es-ES\u0026"],null,null,null,null,"t@131,r@216000000"],null,null,[["http://cbk0.googleapis.com/cbk?","http://cbk1.googleapis.com/cbk?"]],[["http://khm0.googleapis.com/kh?v=75\u0026hl=es-ES\u0026","http://khm1.googleapis.com/kh?v=75\u0026hl=es-ES\u0026"],null,null,null,null,"75"],[["http://mt0.googleapis.com/mapslt?hl=es-ES\u0026","http://mt1.googleapis.com/mapslt?hl=es-ES\u0026"]],[["http://mt0.googleapis.com/mapslt/ft?hl=es-ES\u0026","http://mt1.googleapis.com/mapslt/ft?hl=es-ES\u0026"]],[["http://mt0.googleapis.com/vt?hl=es-ES\u0026","http://mt1.googleapis.com/vt?hl=es-ES\u0026"]],[["http://mt0.googleapis.com/mapslt/loom?hl=es-ES\u0026","http://mt1.googleapis.com/mapslt/loom?hl=es-ES\u0026"]],[["https://mts0.googleapis.com/mapslt?hl=es-ES\u0026","https://mts1.googleapis.com/mapslt?hl=es-ES\u0026"]],[["https://mts0.googleapis.com/mapslt/ft?hl=es-ES\u0026","https://mts1.googleapis.com/mapslt/ft?hl=es-ES\u0026"]]],["es-ES","US",null,0,null,null,"http://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/","http://csi.gstatic.com","https://maps.googleapis.com","http://maps.googleapis.com"],["http://maps.gstatic.com/intl/es_es/mapfiles/api-3/12/11","3.12.11"],[2244818506],1.0,null,null,null,null,0,"blabla",null,null,0,"http://khm.googleapis.com/mz?v=128\u0026","AIzaSyAgUZ1LkdjZ9jsRivdSB4cDLmUAOMOMi34","https://earthbuilder.googleapis.com","https://earthbuilder.googleapis.com",null,"http://mt.googleapis.com/vt/icon"], loadScriptTime);
  };
  var loadScriptTime = (new Date).getTime();
  getScript("http://maps.gstatic.com/intl/es_es/mapfiles/api-3/12/11/main.js");
})();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*EDIT*:  I looked at the script, and its not jsonp, so I modified my answer to use requirejs.

*EDIT* again: It appears that there is some more asychronous jazz going on here. Another edit to bind the global function to the module scope.

Looking at the code returned by that url, it appears that within the code it makes another asynchronous call to retrieve additional data from the api, and then calls your callback.  The only way I can think to do it is to define a global function within your module and use that to handle the return value from the api call.  Its not pretty, but it should work:

```
define([
    "js/util",
    "framework/Controller"
], function (
  util,
  Controller
){      
  function MyController(environment, connector) {
    Controller.call(this, environment);
    this.settings = environment.siteApplication.getSettings();
    this.connector = connector;        
    //Variable where I have some value stored
    this.myVariable = "hello";
  }    

  MyController.prototype = Object.create(Controller.prototype);

  util.extend(MyController.prototype, {
    //Function to show a map
    createRenderer : function(){
       var self = this;
       window.drawMap = function(){
          var mapOptions = {
          center: new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644);,
          zoom: 8,
          mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), mapOptions);
        // Do stuff with self.myVariable and, render, ect...
      };
    },
    showMap: function (request, render) {
      //Get google maps script
      this.createRenderer();
      $.getScript("http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=KEY&sensor=false&callback=drawMap");                     }    
  });

  return MyController;
});
```

Explanation:

When you call `this.createRenderer()`, the function is called in the context of your object.  Since we declare a variable, `self = this`, within the `this.createRenderer()` function call, then define `window.drawMap` within that function call as well, we create a closure, which stores the self reference to the `MyController` object.  When `window.drawMap` is called later, the `self` reference is available in the closure scope.  So now, within the `window.drawMap` function call, we can access `self.myVariable`.  See [How do JavaScript closures work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work) for more information.

As an alternative, you could consider using Miller Medeiros's [async plugin](https://github.com/millermedeiros/requirejs-plugins) to load the Google Maps api as a dependency to your module.  This would be a much cleaner way to do it.

Comment: Thanks for your help @Ryan, but I don't know why, inside the require (where you wrote `//Do stuff with self.myVariable`), I can access `google.maps` but I can't access any of `google.maps.Map` or `google.maps.LatLng`, it's like the api has not been loaded or something... I only could make it working with the global callback function...

Comment: Thanks again, but that's exactly the way I've been proceeding so far :). Well, firstly the function `createRenderer` in the place you put it doesn't work, because it's inside and object, right? so I put it outside `util.extend(MyController.prototype, {...})`, and in fact it works, as I said in my question, but from `createRenderer` I can't acces `myVariable`... (`this` inside this function is `Window`)... so we have been walking around but we're in the same point ;)

Comment: See my explanation added to the end of the post.

Comment: You could also consider using Miller Medeiros's async plugin to load google maps as a dependency to your module. https://github.com/millermedeiros/requirejs-plugins

Comment: Thanks, thanks and a thousand times thanks! after hours and hours of struggling it's working now! Btw, there are a couple of syntax errors in your code that made me confused... And one thing I don't understand is that I've tried and it only works if call the `render(...)` function inside `showMap`, just before the `$.getScript(...)` call... Anyway, scopes and execution order in Javascript is still an obscure world for me... but never mind, it's working ;) Thanks again for taking your time to help me. As I can upvote this answer only once, I'll upvote a couple of answers of yours as a reward ;)

Comment: I saw one sytax error, in the property assignment for creatRenderer (= instead of :) any more?

Comment: Exactly, that was the important one. Then I thought there were some wrong `;` but I can't see it now, so I guess in fact there wasn't any more... thanks again!